# Catching errors thrown with `error`?

Tags: haskell, exception, either

There are some stdlib functions that throw errors on invalid input. For example:

```
Prelude> read "1o2" :: Int
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

I would like to wrap it to return a `Either e a` instead. How can I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[There is no spoon.](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/spoon) You didn't hear it from me.

For this particular example, though, you should use [`reads`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:reads) instead.

Comment: I like the way you phrased it. :) Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to turn errors into values:

```
 maybeRead :: Read a => String -> Maybe a
 maybeRead s = case reads s of
      [(x, "")] -> Just x
      _         -> Nothing
```

Comment: I too prefer that, but the question is about doing it _generally_. `read` is used only as an example.

Comment: I think it is generally true that, for any function which throws an error, there will be a "safe" version of it.