# haskell if exception

Tags: exception, haskell

I have something like this

```
isLastPermutation (h:t)=
            catch (nextPermutation (h:t)) (\e-> return True)
            return False
```

In some cases `nextPermutation` throws an exception and I want my function `isLastPermutation` to return true if `nextPermutation` throws exception otherwise false.

Comment: What is `nextPermutation`'s type?

Comment: consider returning a `Maybe` instead of throwing an exception in your function `nextPermutation`. Then it's just a matter of pattern matching on `Just` and `Nothing`

Comment: As is, that wouldn't compile due to a missing `do`. If you want to throw (and catch) an exception, you must move the `return False` within the `catch`, thus: `catch (nextPermutation (h:t) >> return False) (\_ -> return True)`. But as Mog said, that's not a job for exceptions, use `Maybe` and you don't need `IO` and `catch`.

Comment: nextpermutation uses another function that is throwing an exception,and i want islastPermutation to return true or false if there is an exception,this is how i have to do it

Comment: nextPermutation :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catching errors thrown with \`error\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926855/catching-errors-thrown-with-error)

Comment: Note that the C++ `std::next_permutation()` returns a `bool` (not an exception) to indicate if the permutation has reached the last version, even though exceptions in a C++ context are arguably less dire than they are in a Haskell context.  If your other Haskell function is communicating this kind of information via exception, it is broken and should be fixed!

Comment: I agree with everyone else: rewrite `nextPermutation` and the function it calls so that they don't give an error. If you need help doing that, edit their code into your question and we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use exceptions for flow-control in otherwise pure Haskell. Use `Maybe` or `Either`.